# ROBLOX Get name of a player that clicked a brick

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this script in a brick:

```
local giver = 1

function onClicked()
    game.Players.[I NEED THE PLAYER NAME HERE].leaderstats.Clicks.Value = game.Players.[I NEED THE PLAYER NAME HERE].leaderstats.Clicks.Value + giver
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClicked)
```

Now I need to somehow get the player's name that clicked it and put it where I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ClickDetectors](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ClickDetector)'s [MouseClick](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ClickDetector/MouseClick) event have the "Clicking Player" as parameter, so you can do it like this:

```
local giver = 1

function onClicked(Player)
    Player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value = Player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value + giver
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onClicked)
```

---

However, this requires the [FilteringEnabled](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Workspace/FilteringEnabled) to be set to false (not recomended).

To solve this, make a [LocalScript](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=LocalScript) in the brick with the code:

```
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(function(Player)
    game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("BrickClick"):InvokeServer(script.Parent)
end)
```

And in a [Script](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Script) placed in the [ServerScriptService](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=ServerScriptService) put:

```
local Listener = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("BrickClick")
if Listener == nil then
    Listener = Instance.new("RemoteFunction")
    Listener.Name = "BrickClick"
    Listener.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
end

function Listener.OnServerInvoke(Player,Brick)
    Player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value = Player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value + 1
end
```

---

I won't point you to the [wiki page](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Making_an_onClicked_script) for further reading, even thought it contains a bit of what you need, it contains too little information.

The [ClickDetector's MouseClick info](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/ClickDetector/MouseClick), [the guide about FilteringEnabled](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=FilteringEnabled_with_the_Client-Server_Model) and [the guide about RemoteFunctions](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=RemoteFunction_and_RemoteEvent_Tutorial) are better.

Comment: now I get this error everytime: `02:14:08.231 - ServerScriptService.local Listener = game.ReplicatedStorage:5: bad argument #3 to 'Name' (string expected, got Object)
02:14:08.232 - Script 'ServerScriptService.local Listener = game.ReplicatedStorage', Line 5
02:14:08.232 - Stack End`

Comment: and the script also renames itself to the whole code text

Comment: @TomLenc fixed some faults in the code, but i don't get the part with `the script also renames itself to the whole code text`, there is no way it would rename itself, is there? And how can everything be working if it throws errors at you? O.o

Comment: it changes it's name to: `local Listener = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("BrickClick")
if Listener == nil then
    Lis`
Here's a screensot: http://s22.postimg.org/cco4sv41t/bandicam_91_2.png
    Lis'

Comment: now it says `19:06:49.970 - This function is not yet enabled!
Loaded gloo library. Type _G.gloo.Help() for help.`

Comment: @TomLenc gloo have nothing to do with the code i supplied, it is some other code that seems to be causing that error. And i still do not see how the Name would be set to the code O.o

Comment: Unless you put the code in the `Name` instead of its source?

Comment: The name don't change anymore.. after you made that edit, I put the code there and it works
but why does it say "This function is not yet enabled"?

Comment: @TomLenc it seems that somwhere in some of your code you use the gloo libary (not ROBLOX provided) and that script might use a function that is not yet implemented? Never used gloo libary myself, i tend to build most of the stuff myself. But anyway, the code is working? Increasing the leaderstats on clicks as it should?

Comment: it worked before even with the error...
and without the server and other stuff too..
so yes.. it is working..

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function(Player)
-- Kill The Player
-- The parameter is referring to game.Players So if you want to do a kill button use .Character
Player.Character:BreakJoints()

-- Change The Color To Red (Other details)
    script.Parent.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
    script.Parent.MaxActivationDistance = 0

-- Wait 4 Secs
wait(5)

-- Change The Color To Green
script.Parent.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Lime green")
script.Parent.MaxActivationDistance = 50
end)
```